# Встраивание стороннего приложения в python GUI ошибка

Tags: python

```
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import win32gui
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QWindow, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout,
                             QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QLabel) 


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setFixedSize(230, 280)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(
            QPixmap('images/splash_.jpg').scaled(self.size().width()/2, self.size().height())
        )
        
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.initUI()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1) 
 
    def initUI(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.runExe)
        t.start()
 
        hwnd1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "CalcFrame", "Калькулятор")
        start = time.time()
        while hwnd1 == 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            hwnd1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "CalcFrame", "Калькулятор")
            end = time.time()
            if end - start > 5:
                return
        window = QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd1)
        widget = self.createWindowContainer(window, self.central_widget)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(widget)
 
    @staticmethod
    def runExe():
        exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"
        subprocess.Popen(exePath)

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(550, 400)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: я видел этот код в каких-то предыдущих вопросах и у меня он работает без ошибок.

Comment: @S.Nick Во 2-м питоне проблем бы не было, там деление целых чисел даёт целочисленный результат

Comment: @CrazyElf я не проверял во 2-м питоне, а в python-3.7 - работает без ошибок.

Comment: @S.Nick Но ведь `scaled` действительно хочет `int` ширину и высоту на входе https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html#scaled-1 хотя возможно это линтер ругается, а не прям ошибка совсем.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я читал документацию. А для проверки ставил `555.123` - все работает.

Comment: @S.Nick Может от версии QT зависит? Такие ошибки в принципе гуглятся, но не про эту функцию

Comment: @CrazyElf да, видимо версии QT,  у меня `Qt: v 5.15.2`,    `PyQt: v 5.15.4`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этом месте:

```py
QPixmap('images/splash_.jpg').scaled(self.size().width()/2, self.size().height())
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

В качестве `width` функция ожидает целое число, а вы передаёте число с плавающей точкой. Поробуйте разделить нацело:

```py
self.size().width()//2
```